# How to overlay a vector annotation image on the top of a cartopy map?

Tags: python, layer, cartopy

How to overlay a vector annotation image on the top of a cartopy map?

```
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER

class TDT(cmigt.GoogleWTS):
    def _image_url(self, tile):
        x, y, z = tile
        url = 'http://t1.tianditu.gov.cn/DataServer?T=vec_w&x=%s&y=%s&l=%s&tk=%s' % (x, y, z, mykey)
        return url
        
class TDT_1(cmigt.GoogleWTS):
    def _image_url(self, tile):
        x, y, z = tile
        url = 'http://t1.tianditu.gov.cn/DataServer?T=cva_w&x=%s&y=%s&l=%s&tk=%s' % (x, y, z, mykey)
        return url
        
def make_map(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 13),subplot_kw=dict(projection=projection))
    gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
    gl.xlabels_top = gl.ylabels_right = False
    gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
    gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
    return fig, ax
    
extent = [105, 106, 35.5, 36.5]

request = TDT()
request_1=TDT_1()
fig, ax = make_map(projection=request.crs)
ax.set_extent(extent) 
ax.add_image(request, 10)
ax.add_image(request_1, 10)  #Can't to add another image,how to let it to display on the top of the map.
plt.show()
```

I want to get the merged image with the Vector annotation, but I only see one of the  image.
How do i do?

Comment: Use `alpha` option on the second image. Try this `ax.add_image(request_1, 10, alpha=0.5)`.

Comment: How do you define `merged image`. An example is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you plot two images on top of each other, the top image will hide the bottom completly unless you allow some transparency on the top image. In your case, you can set the second image with the following code:

```
ax.add_image(request_1, 10, alpha=0.6)
```

The value of alpha:

```
0 is 100% transparent
1 is 100% opaque
```

you need a good value between 0 and 1.

In some situation, `zorder` option may be needed.

```
ax.add_image(request, 10, zorder=10)
ax.add_image(request_1, 10, alpha=0.6, zorder=20)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but, whatever i do ,it seemed  there is  a mask on the image.

Comment: It's useful, but it is not what i want.  the request_1 is the png  format images.  it should be opaque. but ...

Comment: an error will appear:" Image.py:952: UserWarning: Palette images with Transparency   expressed in bytes should be converted to RGBA images "